# How to pass input parameters to Start-NewOrchestration powershell command let

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions, azure-powershell, azure-durable-functions

I got requirement to use durable functions for my project work. Our development stack is powershell and I have to trigger orchestrator function from timer trigger function. For triggering I found Start-NewOrchestration command let is used but I have a requirement to pass inputs to it. I couldn't able to find documentation for this command. Can anyone help?

Comment: Is there any meaninful output for `get-help Start-NewOrchestration`?

Comment: I'm getting command let not found error, could you please help

Comment: Have you imported the `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.PowerShellWorker` module yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using below PowerShell Cmdlets:

```
# Client Function - DurableFunctionsTimerTrigger/HttpStart
using namespace System.Net

param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)

$FunctionName = $Request.Params.FunctionName
$InstanceId = Start-NewOrchestration -FunctionName $FunctionName
Write-Host "Started orchestration with ID = '$InstanceId'"

$Response = New-OrchestrationCheckStatusResponse -Request $Request -InstanceId $InstanceId
Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value $Response
```

Or

```
$OrchestratorInput = @{
    'TriggeringTime' = Set-Date '2021-01-01'
}
$InstanceId = Start-NewOrchestration -FunctionName $FunctionName -InputObject $OrchestratorInput
```

Please refer [Azure Durable Functions with PowerShell](https://www.pipehow.tech/new-durableazurefunction/) blog and the [GitHub article](https://github.com/PalmEmanuel/PSDurableFunction) for more detailed information.

[How to pass a POST parameter to a Durable Function and then pass this param to a Timer Triggered function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51966196/how-to-pass-a-post-parameter-to-a-durable-function-and-then-pass-this-param-to-a)

Comment: Thank you got the result as expected. For getting value in orchestrator from context I have used $value=ConvertFrom-Json $Context.Input.tostring()